# Find all embeddings $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ to $\mathbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Here $\alpha$ is a root of $x^6+x^3+1$.

What I figured out:

let $\beta = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{9}}$. $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is the splitting field of $x^6+x^3+1$. Such an embedding must fix $\mathbb Q$, and send a root of $x^6+x^3+1$ to another root. So there are in total $6$ of them. How should I write them down explicitly?

Comment: So why do you mention this $\beta$?

Comment: $\beta$ generates its roots, and I believe this field is actually the splitting field of $x^9-1$.

Comment: What are the other roots of $x^6 + x^3 + 1$ in $\mathbb{C}$? As you say, $\alpha$ must be sent to a root of $x^6 + x^3 + 1$, so we can identify the embeddings by the image of $\alpha$. Moreover, all of these roots can be written in terms of $\beta$.

Comment: Yes, but is locating(which is not hard)all the roots enough for such a problem?

Comment: @Amanda I think so. As you say, $\mathbb{Q}$ is fixed under the embedding, so once you give the image of $\alpha$, you've uniquely determined a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \to \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$x^6 + x^3 + 1 = \frac{x^9 - 1}{x^3 - 1},$$
thus the roots of $x^6 + x^3 + 1$ are the $9$th roots of unity which are not $3$rd roods of unity, i.e. the primitive $9$th roots of unity. The number $\beta = e^{2\pi i/9}$ is a primitive $9$th root of unity, and every other primitive $9$th root of unity can be written as $\beta^m$ for some $1 \leq m \leq 9$ with $\gcd(9,m) = 1$.